# How to solve this height problem?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

*Robert drops a ball from his balcony. The height of the ball is modeled by the function $h(x) = -2t^2 +t +11$. How many many seconds will it take for his ball to reach the ground?*

The correct answer is $t = 2.85$ seconds. However, I tried using the quadratic formula or deriving this equation to solve it but I'm not getting the right answer. Help!

Comment: If he drops the ball then the function of height given by you is wrong.

Comment: What value did you get for $t$?

Comment: I don't blame you, I don't get 2.85 either, I get 2.61 approximately.

Comment: @Unique That depends completely on the situation. It could well be that Robert drops the ball from his balcony on a planet with a gravity of 4 $[1/s^2]$ and that he drops it with initial velocity 1 $[1/s]$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to set the height equal to zero, since that's when the ball hits the ground. Knowing that, now you can apply the quadratic formula to $-2t^2 +t+11 = 0$ to get $$t = \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{89}}{-4} $$ which gives you the answer. I'm pretty sure the 2.85 is just wrong